# Django: What's the best way to create different "kinds" of users and use them interchangeably?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm building a site similar to eBay. I have two kind of users: Sellers and Buyers.

I've read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users and i've created a UserProfile(abstract) model and two other models: Seller and Buyer.

Now, i've other model: Comment. Comment can be wrote by Sellers and Buyers. How should i relate them?
I've been thinking these options, but i have no expirience with Django and maybe you have a better idea:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   created_by =  models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
```

or

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   created_by = models.ForeignKey(auth.models.User)
```

**EDIT:**

I want to have different Classes (Seller and Buyer) becouse they can have different data.

Answer (score 1):

Groups.  It's already part of Django authentication.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#groups

> How should [I] relate them?

Relate to the User.  You get the profile from the User.  You get the groups from the User.

Relate to the primary, central, important entity.  Think of a Profile  as an add-on thing.

Comment: But i have different information for them. Seller and Buyer both have different information to be stored.

Comment: @santiagobasulto: "Seller and Buyer both have different information to be stored"?  Really?  Where does it say that in the question?

Comment: That is why i want to separate classes. I'll add it now. Have you ever deal with it? Some expirience would help me.

Comment: @santiagobasulto: Requirements help more than experience.  User stories help to create requirements.  "becouse they can have different data" is not very informative.

Comment: Becouse that's not the point. I've my user stories, and my requirements and i'm asking how to deal with them. We're not discussing my buisness model, nor my requirements. We're dealing with Django.

Comment: @santiagobasulto: So, I'm supposed to guess what the differences are, and based on my guesses suggest a some kind of design?  All based on random guessing?  Sounds good to me.  That's the answer I gave.